# NUnit & Visual Studio Unit Testing Framework

Tags: unit-testing, nunit, vs-unit-testing-framework

Is there a way to create unit tests that can be run with the [Visual Studio Unit Testing Framework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Studio_Unit_Testing_Framework) as well as [NUnit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NUnit)? I personally prefer the Visual Studio one, but the build server I am using only does NUnit, so I would like to support both if possible.

EDIT: To clarify, I would like to run my own tests using Visual Studio (without add-ons or extensions), but other collegues would like to use NUnit, and the build server needs NUnit. I cannot change anything except the code, so I thought there would be an easy way to satisfy everyone, but its looking to be a bit of a challenge :)

Comment: Which build server are you using? Also which features of VS testing framework do you like better? There might be good ways of doing the same thing in NUnit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you need a Visual Studio test runner. If you install [Gallio](http://www.gallio.org/Downloads.aspx), it will use VS test runner to run any kind of unit tests(xUnit, nUnit, MBUnit). Also [Resharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) and [CodeRush](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/Visual_Studio_Add-in/Coding_Assistance/) have their own test runners.

Answer (score 1):

[Here is one way to do that](http://dotnet.dzone.com/news/another-use-c-using) using precompiler directives and aliases via the "using" keyword

Comment: I have already used that method. It requires a separate binary for either NUnit or VS unit testing (the precompiler directives are interpreted when the code in being compiled, not when it is being executed).

Answer (score 0):

[JustCode](http://www.telerik.com/products/justcode/unit-test-runner.aspx) has a unit test runner that can run tests written using xUnit, NUnit, MbUnit, or Visual Studio Unit Testing Framework.  You can see it in action [here](http://tv.telerik.com/watch/justcode/using-unit-test-runner-with-different-test-frameworks)

Comment: He said build server, though - I expect he means automated from a command-line whereas that page says "inside Visual Studio"

Answer (score 0):

You can write framework agnostic asserts using a library called Should. It also has a very nice fluent syntax which can be used if you like fluent interfaces. I had a blog post related to the same.

http://nileshgule.blogspot.com/2010/11/use-should-assertion-library-to-write.html